# Why does CMake insist that the processor used is x86_64 when it is actually arm64?

Tags: cmake, x86-64, apple-m1

I am using CMake 3.25.1 on an M1 Mac (Monterey 12.4) and am trying to detect the architecture used on an apple machine (so that I can conditionally compile my program to take advantage of M1 acceleration if I can).  The problem is that, with this `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25.1)
project(test)

if(APPLE)
    message("Apple detected...testing architecture...")

    # on macOS "uname -m" returns the architecture (x86_64 or arm64)
    execute_process(
        COMMAND uname -m
        RESULT_VARIABLE result
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE OSX_NATIVE_ARCHITECTURE
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )

    message("${OSX_NATIVE_ARCHITECTURE}")

    if(OSX_NATIVE_ARCHITECTURE STREQUAL "arm64")
        message("M1/2 chip detected.")
    endif()
endif()
```

CMake will tell me that it is using x86_64:
[image: Output of CMakeLists.txt]

What is going on here?

Comment: Seems related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420452/running-uname-m-gives-x86-64-on-m1-mac-mini

Comment: but https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html and `On Apple Silicon hosts, the architecture printed by uname -m may vary based on CMake's own architecture and that of the invoking process tree.`

Comment: @Michael This answer to that question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/449223 is the ultimate answer to my problem.  Thanks for the speedy reply!

Answer (score 2):

As found in the comments, the problem was that the asker was still using the Intel version of Homebrew and needed to install the ARM version of Homebrew. Switch to the ARM version and then reinstall the packages you had before.

A process run with Rosetta or run under any process running with Rosetta will report `x86_64` from `uname -m`.

For more / related info, see:

- [Running uname -m Gives x86_64 On M1 Mac Mini](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/420452/479746)
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html#macos-platforms

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment above, the problem was that I had an old homebrew that had x86_64 CMake installed with Rosetta.  Reinstalling homebrew (but first making a backup `.txt` of my installed packages) and then reinstalling all my packages within the new homebrew fixed my problem.

Note that, if you're in a similar situation, you may need to change some paths set during old homebrew (i.e. `/usr/local/bin` to `/opt/homebrew/bin`)