# CMAKE return CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR with x86_64 on apple M2 CPU

Tags: cmake, apple-silicon

I get CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR return value x86_64(why not arm64) when I run on apple M2 CPU(with cmake version 3.23.0)

The system information and cmake version are as follow:

```bash
╰─➤  uname -a
Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Wed Jul  5 22:17:35 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.141.3~6/RELEASE_ARM64_T8112 arm64
╭─ ‹master*›
╰─➤  cmake --version                                                                                                      
cmake version 3.23.0
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

In addition, when compiling and linking, it will automatically add flags: "-arch x86_64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk"

make VERBOSE=1 print log as below:

```bash
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -L/usr/local/opt/protobuf@3.6/lib "CMakeFiles/arch-dependent.dir/arch-dependent.cpp.o" -o arch-dependent
```

---

This is a test program:

```
╰─➤  cat ../CMakeLists.txt
project(test)

message("CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")

add_executable(test test.cpp)


╰─➤  cmake ..
CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: x86_64
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
...


╰─➤  make VERBOSE=1
...
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test.dir/build
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -MD -MT CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o -c /home/arvin/test/test.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable test
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.23.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -L/usr/local/opt/protobuf@3.6/lib CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o -o test
...
```

1. I can `set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES arm64)` to change x86_64 to arm64, but i want to know what‘s the problem.
2. Although I can add "-Wno-unused-command-line-argument" to mask these auto auto-added flags, I do want to remove from the root.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to provide more details about how do you configure/build your project, and about how exactly you use `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` variable

Comment: I add a test program info, thanks

Comment: Probably, you have the same problem as in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76057246/why-does-cmake-insist-that-the-processor-used-is-x86-64-when-it-is-actually-arm6): in the environment, where `cmake` is executed, `uname -m` returns x86_64 instead of arm64.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=x86_64` you are seeing is because the CMake version you are using is an Intel version and not a `arm64` or universal binary.

For example, my CMake from https://cmake.org/download/ shows

```bash
$ file /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake 
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64]
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake (for architecture arm64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

So it will default to `arm64` when ran on an AppleSilicon Mac:

```bash
$ /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake --fresh .
...
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: arm64
-- Configuring done (0.4s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
```

But if you force it to run as an Intel binary:

```bash
$ arch -arch x86_64 /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake --fresh .
...
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: x86_64
-- Configuring done (1.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
```

So by default CMake will use `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` for `CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES`. If you want to build universal binary, the recommended setting is:

`set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "arm64;x86_64")`

Comment: Thanks for you anwser, and is there a way to turn off these options, because I use the cross-compilation toolchain, which cannot accept parameters such as “-arch ...  -isysroot ...."

Comment: You have to use an AppleSilicon binary and for cross-compilation, you could pass file describing your toolchain via `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`.
You are using which toolchain targeting which OS/processor ?